# DirectShow.Net play MP4 video stream from http responce using C#

Tags: c#, stream, mp4, playback, directshow.net

DirectShow.Net contains really nice player example such DxPlay-2008. I used this example to make couple of video playbacks within a single application. But Unfortunately I can't find how to render video from network stream like following: 
http://www.sampledomain.com:2057/?stream=video&path=media/backbunny.mp4

How to tell FilterGraph to use a network stream instead of a file?
Thanks.

P.S. may be somebody could advise what C# player could play network video stream? I tried VLC in C#. it is almost perfect apart of the issue with libvlc_media_player_stop() function, if I create couple of players and put them on the same form, this function hangs sometimes.
I used is nVlc wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install a Network Source Filter, for example [this](http://www.datastead.com), It will allow you to set a network stream as source. The downside is that you have to paid for it. There are other filters options, I've tried some of them and the have their issues. Datastead is the most stable I've found.

Once you have installed you can use it from Directshow.net using the filter's GUID in the usual way.

Comment: The filter you mentioned works really great. I was able to create 6 instances of the player, open, play and synchronize 6 video streams. Thank you for this. Just wondered is there any free alternative?

Comment: I'm currently working with **ffmpeg**. It's a little more complicated to work with, but is very good. I'm still investigating and testing it. And please if my answer helped, accept it. If you have any doubt regarding ffmpeg, just ask.

Comment: thanks again. I used ffmpeg for other purposes, I didn't know it can play network streams as well. is there something like NET control with ffplay support, so it would be possible to play the video on NET form?

Comment: your help is much appreciated. and answer accepted. thanks again.

Comment: I'm still working on it, I'm currently tying to modify the source code of the ffplay to render the video on a .Net form. The VLC is another option that I know for a fact that can be wrapped in, and used it from a form.

Comment: agree VLC is a good alternative. this is what I use now, but unfortunately if I place 6 players on the same form, function "stop playing" randomly hangs up. Used different wrappers, last one was nVLC.